# how to run a jar on different linux systems at the same time

Tags: java, linux

I have a jar and I need a utility which can read a file containing ipaddresses and run this jar on those systems. How can I do this.

Or what strategy I should apply for this

Comment: **This is not the right forum.** Normally one would use an SSH client in a terminal copy the jar to the server (SSH server) and execute with the jar with the server's java: `java -jar ...`. For a secure SSH user account better take the effort of a key pair.

Comment: There should be a badge for "strange questions"... So you want to read the same file from multiple servers? Just put the jar on every server and run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is missing some key info of what you have, but still you can go like this.

1. Make a script and loop over the ip adresses
2. Copy the jar file to hosts, I assume you have access on them
3. Run the jar

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> while read ipadress
> do
> scp <YOURPATHTOJAR>/<YOURJARFILE>.jar <YOURUSER>@$ipadress:~/
> ssh -f <YOURUSER>@$ipaddress "java ~/<YOURJARFILE>.jar"
> done
> ```

Comment: Nice to the point. This script runs one your local machine and runs the latest jar on the remote servers, by copying and remote java execution.

Comment: I try this but after running first jar on a system it hangs and does not go ahed for further, how can I run jar in seperate process

Comment: what does your jar file do ?

Comment: it runs as a webservice

Comment: if you want your `ssh` to just run your commands and immediately exit, you can use the `-f` option to `ssh`. That will force the `ssh` connection to be a background job

Comment: updated the answer with the `-f` option, check it out

Comment: is there also a way to not to show the output to console returned from the jar

Comment: if you want to hide only the standard output you can add following to the end of ssh command e.g. `java ~/<YOURJARFILE>.jar >/dev/null`