# executing parameter file in a unix remote server

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I am trying to run a script remotely using ssh and the need use some parameters from remote server. Kept all parameters in remote server location  temp/test/test.prm file. Getting an error saying " invoke.sh: line 20: . /temp/test/test.prm: No such file or directory "

See below for sample script. Have very basic knowledge in scripting so plz direct me

```
#!/bin/sh
Param1=$1
Param2=$2

ssh usr@Server1

          . ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm

 cd  $prmHome/$prmSetPath

 ls | sed '/\.log$/d' >  $prmHome/$prmScript/Filelist.txt

 cd $prmHome/$prmScript

 while read LINE

 do

 ExportFilName=$LINE

 ./conversion.sh $prmHome/tmp_export/convert_$Param2.csv  $prmHome/$prmSetPath/'$ExportFilName'

 done < Filelist.txt


rm -rf   $prmHome/$prmScript/Filelist.txt

exit 0



Content of  Sample1.prm
prmHome=/iis/home
prmSetPath=/export/set
PrmScript=/Client/scripts
```

I have tried the same  trough command line after connecting to remote server using ssh and it is working, but when I am trying to do the same through a script (invoke.sh) its throwing  no such file or directory error

Comment: Looks like you're trying to `source` your param file. But why? Is it a shell script or what?

Comment: Or just a general question, what part of your code you intend to run on remote host ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This is unclear and will not work !

```
ssh usr@Server1
          . ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm
```

As mentioned you should use

```
ssh usr@Server1 ". ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm"
```

format first.

And secondly what you expect following command to do ?

`. ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm`

Notice that there is a space in between `.` and the path, which is a synonym for `source`. So also check if the `Sample1.prm` have valid commands.

---

Looks like you are not running any ssh shell command on remote host but only on your local host.

How exactly you are running the ssh shell command ?

The code snippet in your example is poorly formatted.
The general structure should look like this e.g.

- `ssh user1@server1 date`

  or
- `ssh user1@server1 'df -H'`

Please revise you invocation script, or make the formatting in the question appropriate.

Comment: I need to run a script in remote server, but for which I need to pass some parameters.  
I am trying to invoke the same script from local server through another script. So thought in my local script first connect to remote server using ssh( I am not sure whether this is the right way, doing first time )  and then I can read a parameter file  present in remote server and then use some of the parameters from the parameter file as  to run remote script ).

Comment: The code in your question has nothing to do what you want to do. You should use following structure for parameters with multiple command `ssh user1@server1 'df -H'`

Comment: This is absolutely unreadable. Please copy the code into your question and format it !

Comment: .  My intention is  of  '  . ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm '  this command is to execute this file so that I can use the parameters mentioned in Sample1.prm file.  and all the code after this line ( my expectation is ) should  execute on remote server

Comment: You mean your `Sampl1.prm` file is an executable ? if not you have to specify what to execute i.e. an app or script.

Comment: It is executable.  Per my knowledge even if it is not executable if use   like  . file1(dot space filename)   it will execute file1  even if it has not been set as an executable with chmod.

Comment: So have you tried to run your script with fixed ssh command syntax ? Are you still getting the same failure ?

Comment: btw `. `, dot space is synonym for `source`. So does the `Sample1.prm` have valid shell commands ?

Comment: Even After that its failing .  ${Param1}/  is not getting replaced with value  am passing to the main script

Comment: You need to pass in `" ... "` brackets. Your shell will interpolate the ${Param1} before sending the command string to the remote host. Check the updated answer

Comment: Yep its fetching,  but I think it is not executing. also other code after this line is trying to run on local server and not remote server

Comment: If you intend to run the other lines too then the best will be to create a script with the content which you want to run on each remote host. Copy the script to each remote host and then execute it via ssh shell command.

Comment: Check following thread, similar question has been discussed and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213128/how-to-run-a-jar-on-different-linux-systems-at-the-same-time/28213257#28213257

Comment: Thanks deimus. Samuel also replied samething. let me try and will update you both

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you want to execute your code on remote server via ssh, you can do following:

1. Create separate file `my_script.sh` for your code you want to  run remotely, and paste following code:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    function my_function() {
       prmHome=$1
       prmSetPath=$2
       PrmScript=$3

       cd  $prmHome/$prmSetPath

        ls | sed '/\.log$/d' >  $prmHome/$prmScript/Filelist.txt

        cd $prmHome/$prmScript

        while read LINE

        do

        ExportFilName=$LINE

        ./conversion.sh $prmHome/tmp_export/convert_$Param2.csv  $prmHome/$prmSetPath/'$ExportFilName'

        done < Filelist.txt  
        rm -rf   $prmHome/$prmScript/Filelist.txt  

       exit 0 
     }
   ```
2. Then you can call you function remotely, by sourcing your file on remote server:

   `ssh usr@Server1 '. my_script.sh; my_function "/iis/home" "/export/set" "/Client/scripts"'`

That's it :)

---

This code will not work:

```
ssh usr@Server1

          . ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm
```

Change it like that:

```
ssh usr@Server1 ". ${Param1}/Client/scripts/Sample1.prm"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want execute all the code which mentioned after  this line on remote server( server1) only.  how can I do that?

Comment: @Sham hmm, ok but why not put all your code in separate file and then call it via ssh, like that: `ssh $my_server ". /<somepath>/myscpritp.sh; my_function $param1 $param2"` ?

Comment: can you explain little more. put all code means( all code which I need to run on remote server ?)   what do you mean by my_function . Since I posted the code the original  post  can you make out of it. Sorry not much idea on ssh  all

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Let me try and will let you know

Comment: I think the call function syntax is incorrect. not executing

Comment: Ok, my mistake, try that: ssh usr@Server1 '. my_script.sh; my_function "/iis/home" "/export/set" "/Client/scripts"'